# Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Want to start `rake` command but get this problem
`Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`. Here is my gemlist

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails',              '4.1.4'
gem 'json','~> 1.8.1'
gem 'mongo','~>2.5'
gem "haml-rails", "~> 1.0"
gem "sass-rails",'~> 4.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails',       '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails',    '~> 5.0.0'


gem 'cgminer_api_client', '~> 0.2.3'
gem 'cgminer_monitor',    '~> 0.2.18'


gem 'rake',               '~> 10.3.2'
gem 'therubyracer',       '~> 0.12.1'
gem 'thin',               '~> 1.6.2'
gem 'uglifier',           '~> 2.5.3'

group :development do
  gem 'pry'
 source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack', '2.0.1'
gem 'rspec'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'nokogiri'



end
```

If i tring to get `bundle install` it's installing corectly, but when i'm tring to strt `rake` this problem appears again

Comment: What happens when you run `gem install saas-rails`?

Comment: It's installed succesfully, but if i trying to start `rake` it's error again

Comment: What version of `sass-rails` do you have? You can check it in the Gemfile.lock.